# Regarding .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, joomla

I am using Cent OS hosted on VPS. I want to have  the feature of  "Use URL rewriting of joomla". On enabling this in joomla, it gives a message "Rename .htaccess.txt to .htaccess".

I have renamed the file but on opening the website, browser throws 404 error.
The rewrite module is perfectly loaded and for testing redirection, when I add the below in the httpd.conf, the redirection works perfectly. I think, the htaccess file is not being read. 
I have also added the AllowOverride All in the directory setting of my virtual host but nothing changes.

Code Added to httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^joomla\.html http://www.joomla.org/? [R=301,L]
```

My question: Where exactly do we need to add AllowOverride All in httpd.conf ? In the directory `/var/www/html` or my joomla site document root which is `/home/admin/mysite`

Also does joomla use .htaccess to enabling url rewriting? What if we dont want to use .htaccess and only use httpd.conf

Thanks,
Vineet

Answer (score 2):

To allow .htaccess you need add this in httpd.conf but under the module which is configured to server your website.

```
AllowOverride All
```

Editing root httpd.conf not advisable but on the other hand allowing htacess is also not advisable too.you can use vhost configuration and add configuration regarding your website there.It will add extra layer of security on server.